# Magento 1.9.0.1 Homepage session

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, customer-session

I am having problem regarding the `customer/session` on Magento homepage.
Currently i can access and get all Customer information using `customer/session` but not in **Homepage**. In all other pages i can get the customer.
I have also made a clone of project on local machine (Ubuntu 16.04) which is identical as the online server. In local server i can get the correct Customer from session.

When i try to get the customer from session on `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` i get the correct Customer.

in `Mage_Cms_IndexController` in indexAction Method i get empty customer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in which part are you trying to get the customer information and how ?

Comment: I tried getting customer  in controller, in header.phtml. Since i cannot get customer from session i cannot show the right My Account menu and the right shopping cart.

Comment: Have you some full cache module ?

Comment: No and cache is disabled. Even if i had a full cache module the session would work the same in every page. In my case in homepage i have problems. in every other pages no. Even in cms pages it is ok.

Comment: could you show your code? are you using `getModel` or `getSingleton`?

Comment: I guess @simonthesorcerer might be right and you are using getModel instead getSingleton.

Comment: I am usign getSingleton, I have used both of them and still the same thing happens